# Dropbox like syncing using opensource tools

Tags: rsync, dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dropbox alternative](https://serverfault.com/questions/159645/dropbox-alternative)

I would like to setup an automated, dropbox like syncing between two machines which both have Bash/SSH/SCP/rsync etc (they could be Mac, Linux or windows with Cygwin). The syncing should ideally be automated (ie some sort of easy to use GUI based options to schedule downloads, or backups whenever a system gets connected to the internet). It would be nice that if the partial files can be copied (ie if a file is being downloaded to sync folder, its partial contents also get synced)

My searches have turned up http://fak3r.com/geek/howto-build-your-own-open-source-dropbox-clone/ which is based on lsyncd. I would be interested to know more options. Thanks

Edit: The sync will be over the internet. Assume open ports (ie no firewall blocking). The client UI should at least support Mac and Windows. The server can be any of the three.

The above solution probably works, I havent tested it :). I am curious about alternatives. Will look into threads for which I seem to be duplicate. Thanks

Comment: Could be, or do have? You have two machines but you list three (multiboot?) What exactly is your setup and why doesn't the solution you found work? Are you doing it only in-house or over the Internet/through a firewall? There's a lot of vagueness to the question...

Comment: @Bart , pertinents points, Let me address them

Comment: sparkleshare ? May do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.kablink.org/ifolder

That is an open-source port of Novell's iFolder that comes with Open Enterprise Server. It does most of what you're looking for, though like Dropbox it does require a central server to act as a master repo-server. It doesn't do partial-file copies (specifically, I believe it doesn't sync anything with an OS lock on it for safety reasons; you don't want partial-copies of an open Access database) but does have pretty solid conflict-detection build in.

Best of all, has native clients for Windows and Mac. No Cygwin required.

The commercial version (not available separately) does have end-to-end encryption, even on the source-server. Don't know if the OSS version has that.