# Webhost similar to Dropbox with PHP Support?

Tags: php, web-hosting, synchronization, dropbox

I have a website that uses PHP. I need to host it online on a webserver that is similar to dropbox.
I'm trying to look for features that include:

- PHP Support
- Version Control
- Sync Client (windows)
- Public Folder (for online access)

I have tried Dropbox, and Google drive, but both don't have PHP support. I read about [ [Sparkleshare](https://serverfault.com/questions/159645/dropbox-alternative) ], but it only supports "projects" I think. The website I've created cannot be termed as a project for github... cause It's mainly for a company manufacturing and selling products. Also, my IP is not static, so cannot use selfhosted cloud servers, that won't be accessible to people online.

I don't prefer normal webhosts, cause those don't have sync functionality, and files have to be uploaded manually via FTP. Dropbox's public folder functionality is perfect, but dropbox doesn't support PHP.

That's mostly all.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for serverfault.  Maybe you are asking the wrong question and might be better off asking "How can I get dropbox like functionality" on a web provider.  There are a number of avenues worth exploring including "Homecloud" and Using an SSHFS or FTP fS (where the files appear on your computer as a shared drive, but the sharing is done using the ssh or ftp protocol).

Comment: Wouldn't the `FTP fS` take too much bandwidth? I intend to upload this on a free webserver... that would have limits to the ftp usage, right? Also, could you suggest where I can ask this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familer with any service which allow you to run PHP with there storage. But I can tell you how i would do this,

- Buy a VPS
- Install the LAMP/LNMP stack
- Install BTSync / for simple file sharing and syncing
- Install git / svn for version control

Comment: Would the VPS have Online access? Or only LAN/WAN based access? Would the VPS Server need to be on 24/7 for accessing the files?

Comment: It's a VPS you have a full control over it. You can even setup a VPN access to it and then access it via a samba share if you like.

Answer (score 0):

There are different tasks, which you want to do in the same time. Actually, there are 3.

1. You want version control.
2. You want a dropbox-like shared filesystem.
3. You want a webhosting.

The good news is that you can do these everywhere, if you have at least a simple sftp account to a simple webhosting.

The bad news, that it isn't dropbox, thus you will surely miss something, which you don't need, and is solved somehow other as your previous dropbox thing did.

In short:

1. For the version control, I used in your place git. There is a sonamed [gitfs filesystem](https://github.com/rossbiro/GitFS) as well, which can share a git branch as a local filesystem, if you needed that, although you probably don't.
2. There is also [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), which could you enable the local handling of files of a remote ssh filesystem. It is userfs-based as well.
3. A simple sftp/php hosting account can you got everywhere. Probably you don't need us to find the nearest solution.

The live fs-based solutions of (1) and (2) you probably don't need, because git *can* *use* *a* *remote* *repository* *on* *ssh/sftp* *as* *well*!

Here is the linux way. You don't have a simple app which you can install with clicking next, next, next. You have a toolbox, these tools you can combine as you wish.

In your place I used only git, without the (1) and (2) userfs-based extensions, and had 3 repositories:

1. my working tree, where I am editing my files
2. over ssh, on the remote side, it were a simple branch for deploying
3. a remote bare repository, ideally on a remote place, where I use my other branches and backups.

---

I think, you are probably reaching the limits of your previous windows/dropbox world and want to try some new. The bad thing is, that it can't be done without learning them.

I can suggest you [TortoiseGIT](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/), which is a relatively userfriendly dropbox alternative. On the longterm I suggest you try at least one of an IDE Framework (f.e. Eclipse, even for Php), or the command line git tool (in cygwin64, if you have windows).